# Spring Controller - HashMap Return

Tags: java, spring

I have a very basic REST controller...

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/signKey", produces = "application/json")
public class SignKeyController {

@Autowired
private SignKeyService signKeyService;

@GetMapping(value = "/generate")
public ResponseEntity<?> generateSignKey() {
    String signKeyToken = signKeyService.generateNewToken();
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("signKey", signKeyToken);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

returns

```
{
"signKey": "_IjAY736MvwKZLtoJHrhNaD4MUL2r0Al"
}
```

But because I want to return a json object to the frontend, instead of only a string I created an hashmap.
This code works fine but I feel like there should be a better way...

In this case I don't want to create models or anything. This is a simple return of a String. Do I really need to keep creating HashMaps in my controllers which only return some data that is not in any model?

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by better way? It seems good to me, if this model exists only for this controller, you don't need a specific model but it's better to keep some data structure for serialization process. You still can write something shorter `return new ResponseEntity<>(Collections.singletonMap("signKey", signKeyService.generateNewToken()), HttpStatus.OK);`

Comment: yes, it seems pretty fine  and to add to the shortest thing you could also use the
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Collections.singletonMap("signKey", signKeyService.generateNewToken())

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

If this helps , 
you can use [JSONObject](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813) for putting values instead of a Model class.

Example -

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/signKey", produces = "application/json")
public class SignKeyController {

@Autowired
private SignKeyService signKeyService;

@GetMapping(value = "/generate")
public ResponseEntity<?> generateSignKey() {
  String signKeyToken = signKeyService.generateNewToken();
  JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
  data.put("signKey", signKeyToken);
  return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the Link for using [JSONObject Vs HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670586/java-hashmap-vs-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
String signKeyToken = signKeyService.generateNewToken();
DataObj data = new DataObj(signKeyToken);
return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.OK);



class DataObj {
    private String signKey;
    //setter,getter,constructor
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't like defining a data model :-)